# JSF - How to pass a List to a DataTable according with a parameter

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I don't know if it is possible. I try to search but I didn't find anything like that. What I am trying to do is something like that:

```
<p:dataTable  value="#{managedBean.myList("A")}"  ...
```

In my managed bean I will return a list according with the parameter that is passed. For example:

```
public List<Object> getMyList(String param) {
  if ("A".equals(param) { return listA; }
  if ("B".equals(param) { return listB; }
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *A* is a pure String value, you could try with simple quotes and with the complete method name:

```
<p:dataTable  value="#{managedBean.getMyList('A')}"  ...
```

Comment: Thank you! With the complete method name worked perfectly! :)